# Static class in Android

Tags: static

I have a question, I confuss about when I must use class static.

I understand that I have use class static when I need some methods that going to use many times in the code, and that class doesn´t need to be declarate, but in a example in android I find that code.

Where they declare a static class and call it with an instance...

Why did they do that?

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    //View holder pattern
    **ViewHolder holder;**
    if(view ==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

        **holder=new ViewHolder();**
        holder.txtView =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    return view;
}

**static class ViewHolder{
    private TextView txtView;
}**
```

Thanks for your explanation..

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of having a static nested class over an non static one is, that to create an instance of the static nested class you don’t need an instance of the outer class. If you only have a non static inner class you need an object of the outer one to be able to create an instance.

Note that only nested classes can be static.